# How to allow single instance application from the same directory but several instances from different directories in C#?

Tags: c#, instance, executable, single-instance

How could I allow a single instance application started from the same directory but several instances from different directories of the same executable ?

More clearly,

I want `MyProgram.Exe<instance 1>` to be run mono instance from `"C:\Directory1"`

I want `MyProgram.Exe<instance 2>` to be run mono instance from `"C:\Directory2"`

And `MyProgram.Exe<instance 1>` and `MyProgram.Exe<instance 2>` can be run at the same time.

What I'm doing at this time is using Mutex, but I don't know how to achieve this :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static Mutex _mutex = null;
    // Application GUID
    private string _applicationGUID = "4hfd130b-1eh6-4979-bbqc-08g16478c36f";

    public App()
    {
        bool isNewInstance;

        _mutex = new Mutex(true, _applicationGUID, out isNewInstance);

        if (!isNewInstance)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An application is already running. Closing...", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

            Current.Shutdown();
        }
        else
        {
            // Other stuff ...
        }

    }
}
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hash the directory name lower case and chuck it in the named mutex i guess, or maybe you could just use the directory name directly, not sure on what's allowed in the mutex name though

Comment: @TheGeneral, obviously you are right. If I concatenate the `_applicationGUID` with de directory name it works, I just tried it. Could you post the answer ? Thank you.

Comment: @sodjsn26fr you got me interested.. as i like learning new things with regards to c# and available language functionality, So i started looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1 which is just about Mutex in general. could you explain what your requirements are that you need to use Mutex, never used it so wondering under what situation it would be required/beneficial.

Comment: @Seabizkit , you can take a look at https://www.spheregen.com/single-instance-application-using-mutex/ and https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/development/single-instance-winform-app-csharp-mutex-named-pipes/ . Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [`Assembly.Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=netcore-3.1) (or the exe path in general) as the named mutex, with or without your Id.

> Gets the full path or UNC location of the loaded file that contains
> the manifest.

```
_mutex = new Mutex(true, directory, out isNewInstance);
```

or completely overkill

```
var location = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var hs = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
var bytes = hs.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(location));

_mutex = new Mutex(true, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes), out isNewInstance);
```